# Gensim most_similar method coefficients are very low

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I trained word embedding word2vec model using gensim and then used most_similar method to find the most associated words.

```
Word to search:  forest
```

The result is below:

```
Most similar words:  [('wood', 0.2495424747467041), ('trees', 0.24147865176200867), ('distant', 0.2403097301721573), ('island', 0.2402323037)]
```

I wonder why the coefficient is very low, even the top word is less than 0.25.

Thank you!

Comment: how much training data did you use? On what did you train?

Comment: Yes, please describe the training data you've used, an overview of the training code you ran, and the training parameters. It's also curious that your most-similar output only shows 4 words: such output often defaults to 10 results. (If you're only training on text with just 5 unique words, you won't be getting interesting results in any account, as word2vec-like algorithms needs lots of varied data to give meaningful results.)

Comment: I trained on 5 Game of Thrones A Song of Ice and Fire Books. I just showed the first top 4, only for example. I got 20 top associated words, so that is not the problem.     model = Word2Vec(
            train_data,
            size=300,
            window=10,
            min_count=5,
            workers=10,
            iter=1000,
            sg=0)